# How were the Seer's prophecies to Lagertha realized?

Tags: vikings

In Vikings S3E1 "Mercenary", the Seer says to Lagertha:

> I see a harvest celebrated in blood. I see a trickster whose weapon cleaves you. I see a city made of marble, and a burning, broiling ocean.

I think the trickster is

> King Ecbert (edit: or Kalf), who had an affair with Lagertha

and the city made of marble is

> Paris, obviously

But I don't understand the other two. My best guess for the harvest celebrated in blood is

> the failure of the crops in Iceland in season 5, putting the settlers at each other's throats

but Lagertha wasn't there for that.